# How to Submit Azure AD B2C NEW User Submission in MVC App

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Loving Azure AD B2C... Looking forward to when it is out of preview!!!

Have a special case I need help putting my head around.

I have a page where I capture new email addresses via a web form.

After adding that email to my mailing list, I want to then create an AD B2C account automatically without making the user click any additional buttons using my ASP.NET MVC Site.

In reading the Article at: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/

I see that it is possible to add a new user using the Graph API.
However, this example is written using a cmd program.

Does anyone know if there is some sample code to allow me to insert a user into AD B2C inside an MVC controller?

Answer (score 3):

Heres some sample code on how I do it from ASP.Net MVC. Remeber that you need to include ClientId and Clientsecret (they are separate from the ASP.Net webapp) as explained in the article you mention. Code from controller--helperclass:

UserController:

```
  // POST: User/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(b2cuser usr)
    {
        try
        {
            usr.AlternativeSignInNamesInfo.First().Value = string.Format("{0}_{1}", usr.FirstName, usr.LastName);
            usr.DisplayName = string.Format("{0} {1}", usr.FirstName, usr.LastName);

            string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(usr, Formatting.None);
            Utils.GraphAPIHelper api = new Utils.GraphAPIHelper(graphAPIClientId, graphAPIClientSecret, tenant);
            string res = await api.GraphPostRequest("/users/", json);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

And in the GraphAPIHelper:

```
    internal async Task<string> GraphPostRequest(string api, string json)
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(graphResourceID, credential);
        HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
        string url = aadGraphEndpoint + tenant + api + "?" + aadGraphVersion;

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
        request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await http.SendAsync(request);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            object formatted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(error);
            throw new WebException("Error Calling the Graph API: \n" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formatted, Formatting.Indented));
        }

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

And finally, some samplecode from the model, pls note JsonProperty(Order:

```
public class b2cuser
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = 0, PropertyName = "accountEnabled")]
    public bool AccountEnabled = true;

    [JsonProperty(Order = 1, PropertyName = "alternativeSignInNamesInfo")]
    public List<AlternativeSignInNamesInfo> AlternativeSignInNamesInfo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 2, PropertyName = "creationType")]
    public string CreationType = "NameCoexistence";
```